# Unable to write IIS hosted application to a shared folder in Ubuntu but no problem with IISExpress

Tags: c#, iis

I have a shared folder (assets) in the Ubuntu machine and ASP.NET MVC application in a Windows machine. Both machines are in the same network and I have to save files in the shared folder in Ubuntu from the MVC application. When I run the application in **IISExpress**, the application saves the files without any error. But when I host the application in **IIS**, it gives me an error.

> The specified server cannot perform the requested operation.

Here is the code I am using to save the files.

```
  try
            {
                string sourceFile = @"D:\myfile.pdf";

                string destinationPath = @"\\ubuntu\assets/";

                byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(sourceFile);

                System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(destinationPath + Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".pdf", fileBytes);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
```

I played with Identity in Application Pool in IIS to LocalSystem, NetworkService. Any thoughts on how to achieve this goal?

Comment: Could it be a permissions problem at the Ubuntu end?

Comment: https://blog.lextudio.com/web-application-differences-in-visual-studio-and-iis-60fec7e311b3 Please learn what exactly is Local System, Network Service from your domain administrators, and then you understand why using your own account is the right way at this moment. If you want another account to work, the domain administrators can point out what permissions should be set on Ubuntu side.

Answer (score 0):

One way I achieve this is as below:

1. Go to the particular **Application Pools** and click on **Advanced Settings**.
2. Click on **Identity** and click on **Custom account** and click on **Set…**
3. Put window's current login **User name**, **Password** and **Confirm password.**
4. Click **OK** and recycle the Application pool by right-clicking and clicking on **Recycle**.

I don't know if it is the right way to doing.